# How to read the age-out period for deletion from a GCS bucket using Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've configured a GCS bucket to automatically delete objects stored within it after 20 days (did this via the GCP web UI). When I reference the bucket object in Node.JS, how can I get the number of days it's configured for aging out?

GCS Lifecycle Reference is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), but does not provide examples.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with `addLifecycleRule` method and setting the bucket policies?

```html
@example
     * const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
     * const storage = new Storage();
     * const bucket = storage.bucket('bucket-name');
     *
     * //-
     * // Automatically have an object deleted from this bucket
     * // of age.
     * //-
     * bucket.addLifecycleRule({
     *   action: 'delete',
     *   condition: {
     *     age: 20 // Specified in days.
     *   }
     * }, function(err, apiResponse) {
     *   if (err) {
     *     // Error handling omitted.
     *   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of days the object was configured for aging out, that is, the value you set for your bucket in the Console, you must obtain it from the reference to the bucket, not an object within the bucket. You can use the [`bucket.getMetadata()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket#getMetadata) method. This method will call the API, which you can try [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get).

If you would like to know when an object on that bucket will die, you can just get the metadata of that object using the method [`object.getMetadata()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#getMetadata), check the creation date and do simple maths with the value you configured for your bucket.